# At what point is the phrase "couldn't go slower" true.

Tags: limits

I was driving home the other day and my wife made the common remark about a person going slow in the fast lane, "he couldn't go slower if he wanted to!". This made me think, at what speed can you not go any slower WITHOUT stopping?

Comment: This is rather a physics question. If you talk about idealised motion, then you can always go a little slower without stopping. Take your favorite unit of measurement for speed. Take your favorite candidate for “the slowest speed” (such that you can’t go slower without stopping). Measure that speed. Take half of what you got. Move that fast. There you go, a little bit slower than before.

Comment: If you assume that there is a continuum, there is not such a speed (e.g. normalize the speed of your car to $[0,1]$ and you see the issue).

Comment: Scientifically speaking, it's impossible to stop completely. There's always some movement or vibration. You can't make your speed exactly zero.

Comment: It’s another thing if you’re actually asking about the slowest possible speed using a car. Then you would probably have to specify the car, including engine, gears and whatnot, the road, including slope, ground, the possibly weather. I dunno. But you most certainly would have to ask a physicist or an engineer or maybe both, but not a mathematician.

Comment: She was indeed expressing that the car was stopped.

Comment: @k.stm at least with a manual (maybe pedal is better here) clutch I have a hard time to imagine there is any reasonable lower bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can always half the speed, there is no "slowest" (non-zero) speed.

Answer (score 2):

There is none.  For any positive x mph, there is an $\frac x 2$ mph.